# MySQL to MS-SQL server 2005

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, servlets, vaadin

I am developing a Web application , I have written MySQL code for connecting to database , But at my work place they have MS-SQL server , thus Do I have to change full code for database connection or any simple modifications can be done !! Kindly help me out , I am very much new to JAVA,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends,

if you use standard SQL statements you should be able to just specify the new jdbc driver and login information and it should work.
But when you used features from MySQL not available in MS SQL then you will have to modify these parts in the source code.